# Specify device width in HTTP request header

Tags: python, mobile

In Python, I could customize the user-agent and send the request with some mobile type user-agent. However not all sites detects mobile request based on user-agent type.

For example, some sites renders same HTML but different CSS by using media query ('@media ...(max-width: 300px)...').

Is there anyway I can customize the request header to specify the device width to emulate mobile device as much as possible? Or is there any other solution for it?

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : <MOBILE_USER_AGENT>}
request = urllib2.Request(<URL>, None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: Why would you need to worry about rendering sizes? You are not rendering anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are handled by the renderer. The content that is returned by the server doesn't change.

As such, media queries don't have anything to do with HTTP request headers.

Doesn't look like you're rendering anything here, though.